# Join data frames to plot in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some data frames exactly like this onde but with different values:

```
 Route   client_100    client_212    client_748  client_799  client_1774
    1       10.34        0.22        0.62        0.47         1.96
    2        0.97        0.60        0.04        0.78         0.19
    3        2.01        0.15        0.27        0.49         0.00
    4        0.57        0.94        0.11        0.66         0.00
    5        0.68        0.65        0.26        0.41         0.50
    6        0.55        3.59        0.06        0.01         5.50
    7       10.68        1.08        0.07        0.16         0.20
```

each one of this represents a different model that i'm using to calculate this times, i need to plot a line graph to show the diferences between each model(data frames), i think that i need to join the data frames in a single one so i can do that, but i have no idea of how i can do that, so...

Comment: Please conduct the necessary [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). There are countless online docs, tutorials, videos, SO posts of how to `plot` numeric data in R. Give it an earnest try and return with a specific issue.

Comment: For base R plots, start with `plot` and `lines`. Demo: https://rextester.com/HFO41608.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different dataframes with the same variables, and you want to join them in a single dataframe, you likely need to use `rbind()`. Assuming that you have the dataframes A, B and C, `rbind(A,B,C)` should work.